# Adding a secondary element to show where user has dragged slider to in JQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui

Using the normal implementation of JQuery UI slider with this code:

```
$(function() {
  $('.slider').slider();
});
```

JQuery UI only creates the surrounding slidable area, and then the handle to drag. Does anyone have experience extending this add an secondary element that shows where the user has dragged to? What I want to achieve is to have a two colour draggable area, either side of the handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add divs in the slider and update their size on `slide` event. Like this:

```js
$('.slider').slider({
    max: 100,
    min: 0,
    slide: function (e, ui) {
        $('.left-side').css('width', $(ui.handle).position().left)
        $('.right-side').css('width', $(e.target).width() - $(ui.handle).position().left)

    }
});

$('.left-side').css('width', '0px');
$('.right-side').css('width', $('.slider').width())
```

```css
.slider div {
    position: relative;
     height: 100%;
}


.left-side {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    left: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}


.right-side {
    background-color: bisque;
     width:200px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class='slider'>
    <div class="left-side"></div>
    <div class="right-side"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The most comprehensive answer I have ever received on here! Thanks!